# Angular material 'disableRipple' for mat-selection-list not working in mobile

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I should prevent any or all animations that happen while interacting with Angular Material components in my app

The expectation is, when I touch/click an item in the mat-selection-list, It should not show any sort of fadeIn animation as it does normally

I am using `NoopAnimationsModule` and I do not use `BrowserAnimationModule` in my app.module.ts

Following is the code fragment that works fine on desktop but is not working on mobile

```
<mat-selection-list disableRipple (selectionChange)="onValueChange($event)">
          <mat-list-option (click)="proxyClick($event,'checkbox')" (touch)="proxyClick($event,'checkbox')" *ngFor="let item of list"
            [selected]="item.selected" [disabled]="item.disabled" value="{{ item.name }}" disableRipple>

            <span disableRipple>{{item.name}} ({{item.count}})</span>
          </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
```

Just in case, the proxyClick method just helps me stop propagating the click/touch

```
 public proxyClick(event, targetGroupIdentified?: string) {    
    if (targetGroupIdentified) {
      event.cancelBubble = true;
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    }
 }
```

I have tried the following instead of `disableRipple`. They only work on the desktop but not on mobile for a `mat-selection-list` element

1. Have tried `[disableRipple]="true"` instead of `disableRipple`
2. Have tried adding `[@.disabled]="true"` to almost all tags in my HTML file
3. Have tried adding `@HostBinding('@.disabled') disabled = true;`  to my component.ts file

EDIT 1 - Tried the following and it did not help either. Seems like the style change is happening through a code in `core.js` file in `/node_modules/@angular/material` folder and is possibly overriding the style definitions in scss

```
::ng-deep * {
    /*CSS transitions*/
    -o-transition-property: none !important;
    -moz-transition-property: none !important;
    -ms-transition-property: none !important;
    -webkit-transition-property: none !important;
    transition-property: none !important;
    /*CSS transforms*/
    -o-transform: none !important;
    -moz-transform: none !important;
    -ms-transform: none !important;
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
    transform: none !important;
    /*CSS animations*/
    -webkit-animation: none !important;
    -moz-animation: none !important;
    -o-animation: none !important;
    -ms-animation: none !important;
    animation: none !important;
}
```

My Work environment specifications are as follows

```
"@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
```

Appreciate any help/pointers please.

Comment: Have your tried `[disableRipple]="true"` ??

Comment: Yes. I have modified my question with other things related to `disableRipple` that I had tried. Its not working

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same thing, here is my solution: 
Working on Angular 6.

```
<mat-selection-list >
     <mat-list-option  [disableRipple]="true">
     </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

CSS:

```
.mat-list-option, .mat-list-option:hover, .mat-list-option.mat-list-item-focus{
   background: inherit;
}
.mat-selection-list /deep/ .mat-list-item-disabled  h5, .mat-selection-list /deep/ .mat-list-item-disabled mat-pseudo-checkbox {
    color: #b0b0b0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the css is for, but it isn't needed for `disableRipple="true"`. I think the css shown here is just for personal styling for other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.mat-selection-list{ transition: none; }
```

Replace the class with your list class. Try it on option as well.

Comment: It does not work. Have tried a more generic and brutally ugly solution which I have added to the descrption, which did not work either.